# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am getting below error from Jenkins.

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project com-mypoc: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}:
>   The groupId cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]

```
 Jenkins version :2.138.4
    Java version    : 1.8
    Maven version   :3.5
```

Pom file entry:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.2</version> 
            </plugin>
```

Any idea what i am missing ?

given below is pom file content:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <compiler-plugin-version>3.1</compiler-plugin-version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <oracle.driver.version>12.1.0.1</oracle.driver.version>
        <mvn.jar.plugin.version>2.6</mvn.jar.plugin.version>
        <plugin.site.version>3.4</plugin.site.version>
        <parent.version>1.19.1.2</parent.version>
        <versionDescription>SP1911</versionDescription>

    </properties>
    <groupId>org.poc.parallelthread</groupId>
    <artifactId>poc.parallelthread.async</artifactId>
    <version>${parent.version}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>org.batchprocess.jdbc</module>

    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                <version>${oracle.driver.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-taglib</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.50</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </dependency> -->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${plugin.site.version}</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency><!-- add support for ssh/scp -->
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!-- <version>3.2</version> -->
                    <version>3.3.0.603</version>

                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>onejar-maven-plugin</id>
            <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jolira/onejar-maven-plugin</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Jenkins installed version of Sonar

[image]

Comment: Please show the full pom file...

Comment: I have tried with sonar-maven-plugin version 3.2 and 3.3.0.603, its working fine in local  ie i could see these jar in .m2/repository , where as in jenkins its got failed.

Comment: First thing this `<version>${parent.version}</version>` will not work...how have you called Sonar like this: `mvn sonar:sonar` ?

Comment: I have removed <version>${parent.version}</version> in my pom file . mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=<url> is working fine in my machine via command prompt , Jenkins build got failed with same error !!!

Comment: This will not work. `mvn clean install sonar:sonar -D..`...

Comment: yes i agree. mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=<url> , working fine my machine via command prompt. where as it got failed in jenkins with same error

Comment: Configuration the sonar plugin version correctly in your pom via pluginManagement...than it should work also in Jenkins.

Comment: SonarQube servers already configured . which is working fine earlier- existing  stream .Recently i have created the new stream , then this problem begins!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue, using given below steps.

```
1.  Shutdown Jenkins and Sonar
2.  .m2/repository directory removed under users/buildadmin (as libraries are corrupted)
3.  Start Jenkins and Sonar 
4.  Libraries are loaded successfully upon running pipelines and builds were successful from respective stream.
```